# Как растянуть пункты меню по всей ширине родительского блока?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть обычная [навигация](https://jsfiddle.net/m15L3phw/1/):

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Продукция</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Сообщества</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Мероприятия и акции</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Поддержка</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav {
  font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
  background: #000;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #fff;
}

nav li:nth-child(2n) a {
  background: #666;
}
```

Как пункты меню растянуть по всей ширине блока `nav`, чтобы `padding` у всех ссылок был одинаковым (пустого пространства между ссылками быть не должно, это пространство распределяется на внутренние отступы ссылок)?

**UPD:**

Изображение того, как должно отображаться меню.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставить `display: flex` родителю, `flex-basis: auto` + `flex-grow: 1` — потомкам.

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ccc;
}

ul li a {
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ccc;
  display: block;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Продукция</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Сообщества</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Мероприятия и акции</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Поддержка</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на Flexbox

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul,
ul li,
ul li a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul li a {
  min-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Продукция</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Сообщества</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Мероприятия и акции</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Поддержка</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Тот же самый вариант, что и выше :-) Внутренние отступы у ссылок разные.

Comment: Какой вариант выше? Ширина пунктов списка одинаковая, само меню растянуто по ширине. Или вы хотите, чтоб отступы между текстом были одинаковыми?

Comment: В этом и дело, что ширина пунктов одинаковая. Прикрепил картинку к вопросу.

Comment: Теперь понятно. В общем-то ответ вам ниже уже дали.

Answer (score 0):

А этот вариант не проще?

```
ul 
 text-align: justify!important;
    text-align-last: justify;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]